# Can we see traces of exo-moon formation?

Tags: the-moon, natural-satellites, planetary-formation, proto-planetary-disk

Our Moon was likely formed by the collision of a [Mars-size object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet)) with the Earth soon after the planets first formed. Would traces of such an event be detectable by observing the protoplanetary disc around a young star?